# Unsolvable react-native run-ios error on mac

Tags: react-native

So my problem is that when i first installed react-native and created a project (react-native init projectname), it was working properly. i mean when i did react-native run-ios, it was working and i even changed in App.js to hello world and stuff, it was working. 
then i installed open maps and linked them together, and i followed some tutorials on how to open a map on react-native, the last step was to restart it, but what i did was interrupt the terminal close the simulator, and run it again. and since then its not working. I tried everything every solution found online, i even deleted the project and created again. uninstall react-native and reinstall it even the npm. i did the rm -rf ios/build, rm -rf node_modules.... even i found a solution about ports 8081, to kill the pid. nothing worked. all i'm getting is the following. 
i even installed babel. Please help me!!
PS: i'm using mac.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxJ9C.png)

Answer (score 0):

`port 8081` may be used from another app.

You can specify the port.

Let's try this

`react-native run-ios --port=8088`